# С++ Как получить вывод и возвращаемое значение команды batch

Tags: c++

С помощью system можно получить возвращаемое значение. Также, команду можно открыть как файл. В таком случае можно будет получить вывод команды, но нельзя получить возвращаемое значение. Как получить и то, и то?
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

На чистом C++ - только через создание временного файла и перенаправления в него вывода команды средствами командного интерпретатора. Но на практике можно создать нормальный posix-канал и работать с ним, [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478898/how-to-execute-a-command-and-get-output-of-command-within-c-using-posix) приведено несколько способов.